# AngularJS - ngFilter, format input but not ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I want to apply a format filter on an input's text but NOT on it's model, but update the ngModel with the proper ("pure") value when the user changes the value in the input field. Here is what i mean...

For example lets say i have this object:

```
$scope.myObject = {
                value: 1234434.12,
                format:"currency"
            };
```

And this input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myObject.value" format="myObject.format" />
<pre>{{myObject.value|json}}</pre>
```

What i want is:

- The text in the input to be: `1,234,434.12`
- The ngModel's value to be: `1234434.12`

And when the user changes the input text from `1,234,434.12` to `1,234,555.60` i want:

- The text in the input to be: `1,234,555.60`
- The ngModel's value to be: `1234555.60`

As you can see i want to keep the binding but i also want the model to not be affected by the formatting. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the default currency filter provided by Angular.
If you use a filter, only the output to the screen is changed - the internal model remains intact. To see this, you can write something like this:

```
<br>internal model value: <span>{{data.value}}</span>
<br>formatted as currency (USD$): <span>{{data.value | currency}}</span>
```

You'll see that the internal model value is unchanged.

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9N9bQ?p=preview) a plunker with the full code.